# deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' in c

Tags: c

I am working with strings .

Whenever I execute the following program I get an error as ***deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' in c*** on the line `char *p = "hello"`

What am i doing wrong?

What does this error mean ?How can i correct it?

My code is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char *p = "hello";
    printf("%s",p+1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: not error but may be warning...because string literals are `char  const*` types

Comment: const char* p = "hello"

Comment: @user2227862 Read also this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Const-correctness

Comment: String literals are *not* `char const *` in C - they are non-modifiable arrays of plain `char`.

Comment: You need to compile C as C. That is a C++ warning.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This should be a warning (though you may have set your compiler to treat warnings as errors, which is often a good idea).

What you want is: `char const *p = "hello";` instead.

Attempting to modify a string literal gives undefined behavior. The `const` prevents you from doing that by accident (i.e., code that attempts to write via the pointer won't compile, unless you remove the `const` qualifier, such as with a cast).

Answer (score 5):

This is a warning, because "Hello" string is a constant and you are trying to store that in non const char*. To slove the problem either make it

`const char* p = "Hello"` or `char[] p = "Hello"`

Comment: not `const char* p` but `char const *p` some compioler may give you waring for `const char*`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: A compiler *could* generate a warning for almost any (or no) reason, but I'd be at least a little surprised to see one for putting `const` before type instead of after. The standard requires either/both to be accepted.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan can you plz specify which compiler. Because const char and char const both are same I think

Comment: what? I thought const char* is a pointer to a constant char, where as char const* is a constant pointer to a char. in which case only const char* should fix the warning

Comment: I read it some where in past about it, read on [wiki here: const-correctness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Const-correctness)

Comment: @matt const char* and char const* both will make content const and if you want to make pointer const then const shoud appear in between char *const ptr;

Comment: `const char*` and `char const*` are equivalent, both are pointers to constant data (the latter is somewhat poor style however). The placement of the `*` in relation to the `const` keyword is what matters. Don't mix this up with `char* const`, which is a pointer to constant data.